# XPATH Expression - compare derived values

Tags: xml, xpath

Lets assume we have this XML file.

```
<measurements>
  <ms date="2011-05-01">
    <TempMin unit="°C">12.4</TempMin>
    <TempMax unit="°C">18.2</TempMax>
  </ms>
  <ms date="2011-05-02">
    <TempMin unit="°C">19.4</TempMin>
    <TempMax unit="°C">24.2</TempMax>
  </ms>
  <ms date="2011-05-03">
    <TempMin unit="°C">9.4</TempMin>
    <TempMax unit="°C">12.2</TempMax>
  </ms>
</measurements>
```

I want to get the ms element with the highest average temperature - TempAvg is (TempMin+TempMax)/2. How can I do this?

I think my problem is, that I don't know how to get a derived (computed) value of following / preceding siblings. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you use XQuery? It will be more easy.

Comment: Are (Can) you using any programmin language?

Comment: Is it so difficult to do this with XPath alone?

Comment: Indeed I'm not really sure you can do it.

Comment: @Andrew After the flame wars of my answer, I came to the conclusion that it is impossible to do this with XPATH 1.0. Do you at least know which Xpath you are using?

Comment: Note that if you're guaranteed that each `ms` element always has as its children exactly one `TempMin` and one `TempMax`, you don't need to divide anything - the `ms` with the highest *sum of children* will be the one you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It possible with XPath 2.0, but solution has to be a tricky:

```
/measurements/ms[(number(TempMax/number(text()) + TempMin/number(text())) div 2) = 
        /measurements/max(ms/(number(TempMax/number(text()) + TempMin/number(text())) div 2))]
```

For XPath 1.0 probably not - it contains a very small list of functions